# What is the correct way to generate an SSH key fingerprint?

Tags: ssh

I have seen all over StackOverflow answers to questions relating to the generation of an SSH key fingerprint. In these answers, almost always the suggestion is to generate the fingerprint using `ssh-keygen` like so:

```
ssh-keygen -lf <path_to_public_key>
```

However, GitHub's [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-github-apps/authenticating-with-github-apps#verifying-private-keys) suggest that SSH key fingerprints should be creating using the following command:

```
openssl rsa -in PATH_TO_PEM_FILE -pubout -outform DER | openssl sha256 -binary | openssl base64
```

When I perform both commands on the same public key, I get different fingerprints. So my question is which fingerprint is correct?

Comment: There is no universal "correct" way. It depends entirely on the purpose and usage of the key, and the "correct" way should be described in the documentation of the application it's used for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However, GitHub's documentation suggest that SSH key fingerprints should be creating using the following command:

It does not. The documentation isn't talking about SSH keys at all – the article is about PKCS#1-format keys used for the purpose of signing JWT messages (API requests). That GitHub chooses to represent the fingerprint in the "SHA256:<base64>" style popularized by OpenSSH does not make it an SSH key.

In both cases (SSH and PKCS#1/PEM) the fingeprint is a simple SHA256 hash of the public key. However, the key is stored (serialized) in two different formats – PKCS#1 keys use ASN.1 DER serialization, while SSHv2 has its own serialization format.

When the same key is given as input, the actual RSA values (modulus and exponent) will of course remain the same in both cases, but they're framed differently, might be in different order, and additional fields might be present in one format but not the other.

(Think it of having a JSON document and a YAML document. They may represent the same data and be directly convertible from one to the other, but will still have different hash values.)